# @click event not changing data property in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `v-for` loop in Vue.js. It has to iterate through a list to create buttons. I added a click event on them, so `upUrl` changes and takes their button index for its value:

```
    <div class="mt-3" v-for="(buttonPic, index) in buttonPics"
                      :key="buttonPic"           
    >
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
    @click="upUrl= index">
   {{ buttonPic }} </button>
    </div>
```

I have `upUrl:null` in `data()` but checking in the Vue Google Chrome Console, I can see that `upUrl` is never updated, and always equal `null`.

I've tried using `@click="upUrl= this.index">` but I get an error: '`index' is defined but never used`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, check the following example :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      upUrl: null,
      buttonPics: ["pic1", "pic2", "pic3"]

    }
  },
  watch: {
    upUrl(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal, oldVal)
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <div class="mt-3" v-for="(buttonPic, index) in buttonPics" :key="buttonPic">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" @click="upUrl= index">
   {{ buttonPic }} </button>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: My mistake was that I defined `buttonPics[ ]` before `upUrl` in my `data()`. I didn't knew the order was important.

Comment: Now If I take off {{ upUrl }} , it doesn't change in my Vue Google Chrome Console.Does its value changes anyway?

Comment: the order doesn't matter, please share how do you log it in console

Comment: I didn't logged it into the console, I was just looking at the Vue Google Chrome Console Extension.

Comment: you mean vue devtools

Comment: the data is changing and you could prove that by watching it as i did in my edited answer